# How to modify the `nodePort` range when using Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I tried to open `nodePort 80/443`, but it failed because it was outside the default `nodePort` range.

Solution is add `- --service-node-port-range` option to static pod `kube-apiserver-docker-desktop`. But how can I modify the static pod using Docker Desktop on Windows? I tried to edit this pod directly but failed.

```bash
kubectl edit pod kube-apiserver-docker-desktop -n kube-system
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to modify the nodePort range, but I change my ingress controller service type to `LoadBalancer` to approach my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a privileged docker container :

```
$ docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

Then edit kubernetes configuration here :

```
$ vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

Add the command line param in the list with the ports you need:

```
        - --service-node-port-range=80-36000
```

This StackOverflow question explain how to process :

[Location of Kubernetes config directory with Docker Desktop on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758012/location-of-kubernetes-config-directory-with-docker-desktop-on-windows)

Comment: $ k describe po/kube-apiserver-docker-desktop --namespace kube-system
// 
--enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,AlwaysPullImages