# Location of Kubernetes config directory with Docker Desktop on Windows

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am running a local Kubernetes cluster through Docker Desktop on Windows. I'm attempting to modify my kube-apiserver config, and all of the information I've found has said to modify `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on the master. I haven't been able to find this file, and am not sure what the proper way is to do this. Is there a different process because the cluster is through Docker Desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a different process because the cluster is through Docker Desktop?

You can get access to the `kubeapi-server.yaml` with a Kubernetes that is running on Docker Desktop but in a "hacky" way. I've included the explanation below.

For setups that require such reconfigurations, I encourage you to use different solution like for example `minikube`.

`Minikube` has a feature that allows you to pass the additional options for the Kubernetes components. You can read more about `--extra-config ExtraOption` by following this documentation:

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Commands: Start](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/)*

---

As for the reconfiguration of `kube-apiserver.yaml` with Docker Desktop

You need to run following command:

```bash
docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

Above command will allow you to run:

```bash
vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

This lets you edit the API server configuration. The `Pod` running `kubeapi-server` will be restarted with new parameters.

You can check below StackOverflow answers for more reference:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Where are the Docker Desktop for Windows kubelet logs located?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720511/12257134)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: How to change the default nodeport range on Mac (docker-desktop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57588995/12257134)*

  > I've used this answer without `$ screen` command and I was able to reconfigure `kubeapi-server` on Docker Desktop in Windows