# Istio allow third party JWT on Docker Desktop Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I'm using the pre-packaged Kubernetes cluster that comes with docker desktop. I'm on a windows machine, running the Kubernetes on a Ubuntu-18.04 VM using WSL 2. On my Kubernetes cluster I run:

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo --set values.global.jwtPolicy=third-party-jwt
```

But I get the message:

```
Detected that your cluster does not support third party JWT authentication. Falling back to less secure first party JWT. See https://istio.io/v1.9/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens for details.
```

After that, it freezes on this until it times out:

```
Processing resources for Istiod. Waiting for Deployment/istio-system/istiod
```

Is there a way of enabling third party JWT in my cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error message that you've received there is a link that points to the documentation on that specific issue:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Ops: Best practices: Security: Configure third party service account tokens](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens)*

Citing the official documentation:

> #### Configure third party service account tokens
>
> To authenticate with the Istio control plane, the Istio proxy will use a Service Account token. Kubernetes supports two forms of these tokens:
>
> Third party tokens, which have a scoped audience and expiration.
> First party tokens, which have no expiration and are mounted into all pods.
> Because the properties of the first party token are less secure, Istio will default to using third party tokens. However, this feature is not enabled on all Kubernetes platforms.
>
> If you are using istioctl to install, support will be automatically detected. This can be done manually as well, and configured by passing `--set values.global.jwtPolicy=third-party-jwt` or `--set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt`.
>
> To determine if your cluster supports third party tokens, look for the TokenRequest API. If this returns no response, then the feature is not supported:
>
> `$ kubectl get --raw /api/v1 | jq '.resources[] | select(.name | index("serviceaccounts/token"))'`
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "serviceaccounts/token",
>     "singularName": "",
>     "namespaced": true,
>     "group": "authentication.k8s.io",
>     "version": "v1",
>     "kind": "TokenRequest",
>     "verbs": [
>         "create"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> While most cloud providers support this feature now, many local development tools and custom installations may not prior to Kubernetes 1.20. To enable this feature, please refer to the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection).

---

I'm not sure if this feature is supported by Kubernetes (`1.19.7`) created with Docker Desktop but Kubernetes documentation shows a way how you could enable it:

> #### Service Account Token Volume Projection
>
> **FEATURE STATE:** Kubernetes v1.20 [stable]
>
> **Note:**
>
> To enable and use token request projection, you must specify each of the following command line arguments to kube-apiserver:
>
> ```
> --service-account-issuer
> --service-account-key-file
> --service-account-signing-key-file
> --api-audiences
> ```

You can edit your `kubeapi-server` manifest in a Docker Desktop with Kubernetes in a somewhat hacky way. You can read more about it by following this answer (which I am the author of):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Location of Kubernetes config directory with Docker Desktop on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758012/location-of-kubernetes-config-directory-with-docker-desktop-on-windows/64774052#64774052)*

---

#### Workaround

As you are using Docker on your host, you could also consider using `minikube` with its `--driver=docker`. It supports third party JWT tokens as described in the Istio documentation (it produces the response from the `$ kubectl get --raw ...` command).

> A side note!
>
> I've tested this on a `minikube` version `1.19.0` and Kubernetes version `1.20.2`.